# Add terraform log message after resource creation

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I have built custom terraform provider, now for the finishing touch I would like to add some message in "STRING" format after resource has done creating.

The problem i am facing is I am using terraform framework and the only way I can add text after resource creation I found was this

```
 (r *vmResource) Create(ctx context.Context, req resource.CreateRequest, resp *resource.CreateResponse){


diags.AddWarning(
            "",
            "Some String message",
        )

}
```

The problem is that this will result in truncated message for one resource alone,

**Resource number one successfully created.**

**│ (and one more similar warning elsewhere)**

**Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 2 destroyed.**

I have tried using fmt.Printf() and all other methods fmt offers, even tried using log.Print() but none seem to work.
**
I need to handle this in: func (r *vmResource) Create(ctx context.Context, req resource.CreateRequest, resp resource.CreateResponse) **
**not in Main.tf**

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

I have tried to output resource information after it is being created, however I get a truncated message for only one resource and that message is in form of Warning.

I am expecting to output non Warning message that is not truncated with all I need.

Comment: Warnings are intended for describing unexpected but non-fatal problems that the user should typically aim to correct before applying again. An object being created successfully is not an appropriate thing to describe in a warning. There is no way for a provider to change how Terraform renders (or how it coalesces) the warning messages.

Comment: What can i use instead of that?